# http 1.1 pipeling client implementation

Tags: java, http, pipeline

What would be the programming model for an http 1.1 client implementation with support for pipeling? I am interested in pipeling POSTs.

Answer (score 0):

You question seems to be back to front to me. If you're interested in pipelining you must already have a programming model in mind. And the RFC does say that POST shouldn't be pipelined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you mentioned it is a SHOULD mandate not a MUST. I have a simple model in mind, lock an http connection output stream and input stream to allow multiple active POSTs. Looking in google though I could not find an implementation that actually implements HTTP pipelining. Not even apache httpclient. I am wondering if this feature can be implemented (i.e. properly supported by servers compliant to HTTP1.1) or it can only theoretically be implemented and I should not go after this approach

Answer (score 0):

As EJP already mentioned, POSTs shouldn't be pipelined. But since "SHOULD" is not "MUST", I'll be adding pipelining support (yes, POSTs will also be supported) to [hotpotato](http://hotpotato.factor45.org/) pretty soon.

Not sure whether you're looking for an existing implementation or wanting to make one of your own... Either way, that project could come in handy :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also work under way by a developer to add HTTP pipelining support for [Async HTTP Client](http://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) at github.

With respect to pipelining POSTs, one might want to read "should not" pretty much same as "DO NOT" -- if standard specifier thinks it's a bad idea, maybe it is? -- but perhaps there are specific use cases where it is well known that general unknowns with POSTS (lack of idempotency) are not true, and thereby it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think jboss's [netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty/) supports pipelining.

Have a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453602/highly-concurrent-http-with-netty-and-nio)** for more details.