# Highly concurrent HTTP with Netty and NIO

Tags: java, http, concurrency, clojure, netty

I am working through the [example Netty HTTP Client code](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/snoop/package-summary.html) in order to make http requests within a concurrent, threaded environment.

However, my system breaks completely (with a slew of exceptions) at fairly low throughput.

In almost pseudo-code:

```
ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(new NioClientSocketChannelFactory()) 
bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new HttpClientPipelineFactory());

ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
Channel channel = future.awaitUninterruptibly().getChannel();

HttpRequest request = new DefaultHttpRequest();
channel.write(request);
```

In the example, to make a request I create a ClientBootstrap, and from there (through a few hoops) a Channel to write the HTTPRequest.

This all works and is good.

However, in a concurrent situation, should every request be going through the same hoops? I think that is what's breaking things for me at the moment. Should I be reusing the connection or structuring my client in an entirely different way?

Also: I am doing this in Clojure, if that makes any difference at all.

Comment: maybe you should use https://github.com/ztellman/aleph ?

Comment: do you have experience with aleph? I have tried another async clojure http client, but it doesn't work at the levels of throughput I need to sustain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you're doing things right. You must, however, keep a reference to your `Channel` instance. Once you have that channel, as long as it is open, you don't need to create another bootstrap. (If that's what you're doing.)

This is what I used in a recent project :

**class ClientConnection** *(constructor)*

```
// Configure the client.
bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(
    new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
        Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
        Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
    )
);

// Set up the pipeline factory.
bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(
    new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            return Channels.pipeline(
                // put your handlers here
            );
        }
    }
);
```

**class ClientConnection.connect(String host, int port)**

```
if (isConnected()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("already connected");
}

// Start the connection attempt.
ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));

channel = future.awaitUninterruptibly().getChannel();

// Wait until the connection is closed or the connection attempt fails.
channel.getCloseFuture().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Shut down thread pools to exit
                // (cannot be executed in the same thread pool!
                bootstrap.releaseExternalResources();

                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Shutting down");
            }
        }).start();
    }
});
```

So, basically, I only keep a reference to `bootstrap` and `channel`, however the former is pretty much not used outside of these lines of code.

**Note:** you should only execute `bootstrap.releaseExternalResources();` once, when the application is exiting. In my case, the client sends some files then close the channel and exit.

Once you have a connected `Channel` instance, you need only to use that one until you close it again. Once it is closed, you can recall the `bootstrap` to create a new `Channel` again.

Personally, I find Netty a little bit hard to understand at first, but once you grasp how it works, it is simply the best NIO framework in Java. IMO.

Comment: `bootstrap` will also be useful if you want to make another connection and utilize existing machinery (underlying Netty NIO worker threads).

Answer (score 1):

Netty is the best approach to writing highly concurrent HTTP services in the JVM but it is very complicated and hard to interop with directly, especially if using Clojure. Take a look at Donkey which provides interop with Vert.x which uses Netty as the backend. This layering abstracts away a lot of the nuanced low level details that, if done wrong, can result in an unstable service. Donkey is relatively new so there isn't a lot of documentation about it yet. Check out this [blog](https://glennengstrand.info/software/architecture/microservice/clojure/vertx) that features an open source project which implements a rudimentary news feed microservice in Clojure using Donkey. It goes into details on architecture, design, coding, and performance under load.