# Non-blocking queue of HTTP POST requests with persistence

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, message-queue

Before we develop our custom solution, I'm looking for some kind of library, which provides:

*Non-blocking queue of HTTP requests*

with these attributes:

- Persisting requests to avoid it's loss in case of:

  - network connectivity interruption
  - application quit, forced GC on background app
  - etc..
- Possibility of putting out all these fields:

  - Address
  - Headers
  - POST data

So please, is there anything usable right know, what could save us whole day on developing this?

Right now we don't need any callbacks on completed request and neither saving result data, as there won't be such.

Comment: looks like you'll need to develop one.

Comment: @ChenKinnrot I just hope this is kind of common problem we should have had solved for ages on Android platform.

Comment: I didn't meet such kind of problem, but I don't think it is difficult to roll your own implementation. With Java non-blocking IO, you start a server socket to accept all requests concurrently, save raw bytes of everything posted to you, process the requests later the way you like.

Comment: @MarekSebera, If I understand correctly, you are trying to persist the request the moment you receive it. Is this expectation is at raw socket level (raw request) or on some higher level where the request is parsed ?

Comment: @Santosh, I'm trying to persist the requests when offline, or when many requests are generated from client application, to be later send based on network availability and httpclient concurrency to server. Persisted to local filesystem/db/whatever for cases where user will quit the application or GC will kill it in background. I have no interest in parsing response from server (but it would be bonus feature). In request I need to specify additional headers, URL and POST data (if declared the request is POST not GET)

Comment: you'll have to develop one most likely, I developed a similar custom solution for one app, following the advice on this Google I/O http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html, the main part is that you have to persist your web calls using a table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my humble opinion, a good and straightforward solution would be to develop your own layer (which shouldn't be so complicated) using a sophisticated framework for connection handling, such as **Netty** https://netty.io/ , together with a sophisticated framework for asynchronous processing, such as **Akka** http://akka.io/

Let's first look inside **Netty** support for http at http://static.netty.io/3.5/guide/#architecture.8 :

4.3. HTTP Implementation

HTTP is definitely the most popular protocol in the Internet. There are already a number of HTTP implementations such as a Servlet container. Then why does Netty have HTTP on top of its core?

Netty's HTTP support is very different from the existing HTTP libraries. It gives you complete control over how HTTP messages are exchanged at a low level. Because it is basically the combination of an HTTP codec and HTTP message classes, there is no restriction such as an enforced thread model. That is, you can write your own HTTP client or server that works exactly the way you want. You have full control over everything that's in the HTTP specification, including the thread model, connection life cycle, and chunked encoding.

And now let's dig inside **Akka**. Akka is a framework which provides an excellent abstraction on the top of Java concurrent API, and it comes with API in Java or Scala.

- It provides you a clear way to structure your application as a hierarchy of **actors**:

  - Actors communicate through message passing, using immutable message so that you have not to care about thread-safety
  - Actors messages are stored in message boxes, which can be durable
  - Actors are responsible for supervising their children
  - Actors can be run on one or more JVM and can communicate using a wide numbers of protocols
- It provides a lightweight abstraction for asynchronous processing , **Future**, which is easier to use then Java Futures.
- It provides other fancy stuff such as Event Bus, ZeroMQ adapter, Remoting support, Dataflow concurrency, Scheduler

---

Once you become familiar with the two frameworks, it turns out that what you need can easily be coded through them.

In fact, what you need is an http proxy coded in Netty, that upon a request receival sends immediately a message to an **Akka Actor** of type **FSM** (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/java/fsm.html) which using a **durable mailbox** (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/modules/durable-mailbox.html )

Comment: Wow, super answer, I need to look up all mentioned, but this really looks like solution suitable for enterprise/business usage. I just wonder (and I need to investigate a bit) how it will enlarge the application size (needed libraries size) and how is it easy to implement in existing solution :))

Comment: If you are comfortable with trying to learn some Scala, I can promise you will make it in less then 1000 lines of code, because of Scala conciness. And of course Scala compiles to legal Java bytecode so all would be interoperable

Comment: Sure, I've met Scala in one of recent Spring project, and it looks like, it's time to move on from standard Java to Scala/Groovy/etc.. as these are making fast and great progress in recent times :)

Comment: Please also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453602/highly-concurrent-http-with-netty-and-nio

Comment: An additional comment: since there is no widely adopted solution going for an internal development will have higher initial costs but reduced  maintaining and upgrading cost, while if you get code who was written by someone else ...good luck!

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://www.assembla.com/code/ltprotocol/subversion/nodes) is a link to open-source library that was a Master Thesis of a student at Czech Technical University in Prague. It is very large and powerful library and mainly focuses on location. The good thing about it, though, is that it omitted the headers and other -ish that REST has.

It is the latest fork and hopefully it will give you at least inspiration for "own" solution.

Answer (score 1):

how about those concurrent collections:

http://mcg.cs.tau.ac.il/projects/concurrent-data-structures

i hope that the license is ok .

Comment: Could you please extends your answer with an example? I'm not able to recognize which of these 7 concurrent data structures and should answer my question.

Comment: the collections are very basic , even more than those of java . the reason is that they need to be concurrent . more effort was done on performance . in any case , you wrote that you need a queue , so choose a queue , and make it fit your needs (since you need to make it work with http requests) . those collections are very generic . they are supposed to work with any data type.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to have a look to these to posts. (added at the end of the document)

Very basically an approach that works in a proficient way for me is to separate requests from the queue and the executor.
Requests are executed as Runnables or Callables. Inherit from them to create different kind of requests to your API or service. Set them up there adding headers and or body prior to to executing them.

Enqueue those requests in a queue (choose which fits better for you - I'd say [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) will make the job) linked to an executor from within a bound service and calling them from your activity or any other scope. If you don't need to get responses and callbacks you can avoid using Guava for listening to futures or create your own callbacks.

I'll stay tuned. If you need more depth I can post some specific pieces of code. There's the source of a basic example in the first link though.

http://ugiagonzalez.com/2012/08/03/using-runnables-queues-and-executors-to-perform-tasks-in-background-threads-in-android/

http://ugiagonzalez.com/2012/07/02/theres-life-after-asynctasks-in-android/

Update:

You can create another queue for those requests that were impossible to execute.
One approach that comes to my mind would be to add all your failed requests to the retry queue. The retry queue would be trying to re-run these tasks while the phone still thinks that there's any kind of internet connection available. In the request object you can set a max number of retrials and compare it to a currentRetry number increasing it in every retrial.
Mmm this might be interesting. I'll definitely think about including that in my library.

Comment: Thank you José for your input, this what you're talking about is solution to enqueuing tasks to some Executors service, which will work on them. Your answer touches only about half of the problem. The main problem is to persist the requests in some simple-minded way, and to let them be executed on remote server as soon as we have network connection and remove them from queue only on successfully send request (probably defined by HTTP result code). So the cycle provided by library/package is asynchronous request queue with persisting requests on network absence.